# What is am Doing wrong in ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

In PHP I am using this

```
if(!f || !f2)
```

Now I am converting this code into ASP like this

```
If Not f OR Not f2 Then
```

but it gives me an error:

```
Error Type:
Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01B6)
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

What I can do now?

Comment: `||` is logical *OR*, not AND.

Comment: @Mark Byers :) Sorry I am using OR here after that i gives an error like this

Comment: My whole coding is here http://pastebin.com/5Wqd6kk2

Answer (score 2):

Because `f` and `f2` are objects, I think the ASP is assuming that they have default properties which you're trying to test in

```
If Not f OR Not f2 Then
```

which is why you get that error message (for example if the default property was `Name`, you'd actually be testing `If Not f.Name OR Not f2.Name Then`).

What you probably want to do is test to see if they are invalid objects, which you can do by

```
If (f Is Nothing) OR (f2 Is Nothing) Then
```

Comment: If f or f2 have not been specifically `Set` with an object or `Nothing` this code will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you really need is to check whether those files exist or not - classic ASP has different logic than PHP.

So try using this code instead:

```
Dim fp1, f, f2
Dim vid, vkey
Dim enc, enc1, enc2
set fp1 = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fp1.FileExists(vid_file) And fp1.FileExists(vkey_file) Then
    set f = fp1.OpenTextFile(vid_file, 1, true)
    set f2=fp1.OpenTextFile(vkey_file, 1, true)
    vid = Trim(f.ReadLine)
    vkey = Trim(f2.ReadLine)
    f.Close
    f2.Close
    Set f = Nothing
    Set f2 = Nothing

    enc1 = hex_sha1(vid)
    enc2 = hex_sha1(vkey)
    enc = enc1 & enc2
Else  
    Response.Write "Vendor authentication failed."
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need [IsObject()](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_isobject.asp).

Try

```
If Not IsObject(f1) Or Not IsObject(f2) Then ...
```

Comment: if `f1` or `f2` is Nothing `IsObject` still returns true.